# Trying to get the current value of a UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

My app is a slideshow that changes once a minute with a photo corresponding to each minute in the day. I currently have it checking the time and updating the image every tenth of second, as this will be on many devices at a large public event.

The relevant bits are:

```
@IBOutlet weak var theBrokenWatch: UIImageView!

if theBrokenWatch.image != UIImage(named: theImageName as String) {
    theBrokenWatch.image = getUncachedImage(named: theImageName)
    print("changed image to", theCurrentTime as String)
}

func getUncachedImage (named name : String) -> UIImage? {
    if let imgPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(name, ofType: nil) {
            return UIImage(contentsOfFile: imgPath)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Right now the `if` statement doesn't work. It did work when I was setting the image using `imageNamed:`, but that had major memory issues with 720 photos. (The CurrentTime is calculated and the matching image path built as theImageName.)

How can I check to see if the image needs to be changed (i.e. it's not what I just calculated as the current time)?

Comment: What are you actually checking with the if statements?  I don't think it should work in any case.  You are creating a new UIImage object with a different location in memory which will not be same as previous UIImage object you created even though it's the same image. imagedNamed possibly worked because it was caching images.

Comment: I was trying to check to see if the current image needed to be changed. So at 12:37, is the image 1236.jpg?

So using contentsOfFile makes each UIImage unique, and uncheckable? If theBrokenWatch (where the image is shown) is the place that always gets the image, I think I should be able to check it, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use an uncached image to check for equality. Each time its generated, the image object will be different (the image *data* will be the same, but the wrapper object will be re-generated, and therefore not equal; image equality is not based of of actual bit contents).

Instead, key off the image name. Create a new var, imageName, and set that when you set the image. Then, when your timer fires, check your cached imageName against the new one, and only change the .image var if they're different.

Comment: This fixed it, and it streamlined some of what I was doing. Thanks!